# Constant World Translations when determining Height above Terrain

Tags: unreal-engine4, world-coordinates

Firstly, I was trying to retreive current terrain altitude as in this topic: [How to get altitude above terrain - https://community.cesium.com/t/how-to-get-altitude-above-terrain/19802/3 (shortly: place a component on a Pawn below by some significant distance so it would be lower then terrain level and retreive current height above terrain by projecting a ray with LineTraceByChannel).
But I bumped into a problem: when I am moving around with my Pawn I noticed that the world’s origin keeps being rebuilt (which affects current altitude above terrain).
Example from logs:

```
LogLevel: WORLD TRANSLATION BEGIN {172119, -234008, -274360} -> {162435, -243913, -284556}
LogLevel: WORLD TRANSLATION END {162435, -243913, -284556} took 0.7787 ms
```

I decided to try flying with DynamicPawn and the result was the same.
According to this topic: [Is World Origin Rebasing working? - World Creation - Epic Developer Community Forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/is-world-origin-rebasing-working/412310)
I figured out that there is a UWorldComposition somewhere and it has *RebaseOriginDistance* property which I would like to change and test if it will affect my problem.
But when I tried to get WorldComposition with

```
    UWorldComposition* WorldComposition = GetWorld()->WorldComposition;
```

it turned out that WorldComposition is nullptr. I tried doint it inside BeginPlay event of my Pawn and inside Constructor also (just to be sure).

So I have two questions:

1. Are there any workarounds that prevent World Translation? (I suppose the most straightforwarded is just increase RebaseOriginDistance)
2. How can access WorldComposition so it won’t be nullptr? Should I create it somehow by myself or make a component which would be inherited from it?
3. Is there a better way to get current altitude above terrain with cesium and unreal?

***Upd:***
For future generations here is the answer:
https://community.cesium.com/t/constant-world-translations-when-determining-height-above-terrain/27133